# How to iterate through a vector of vectors?

Tags: loops, vector, common-lisp

I have a data structure like this:

```
(defparameter *test*
  #(#(3)
    #(7 4)
    #(2 4 6)
    #(8 5 9 3)))
```

which represents a triangle of integers and a function

```
(defun get-node (i j triangle)
  "Returns the value of the node I J of TRIANGLE."
  (assert (<= j i) (i j) "~&J has to be smaller than I! I: ~D J: ~D~%" i j)
  (svref (svref triangle i) j))
```

which allows me to access each node of the triangle easily (at least I think it does).

I thought using these two it would be easy to build up the sum along different paths through the triangle from top (3) to bottom, e.g. 8 --> 3 + 7 + 2 + 8 = 20. The next path would be 3 + 7 + 2 + 5 = 17.

Unfortunately, I totally fail to generate the indices of my vector of vectors in a reasonable way to find all the eight path in this simple example. This is not about brute-force vs. dynamic programming, etc. I am just looking for a way to iterate through the columns and rows of `*test*` which assures that each path was found.

How could one iterate the two indices, e.g. `i` and `j` in such a way that the correct combinations are found?

Comment: what paths? `3 + 7 + 2 + 5 = 15`? What path is that? 15? Not 17?

Comment: Sorry, stupid typo!

Comment: (1) Do we have to use vectors? Especially at the top level? (2) What does one of your failing efforts look like? (3) Yes, your description of the task needs work. I realize now it is like a ball dropping down an inverted pyramid of pegs going either left or right.

Comment: (1) No, I just thought it would be the most compact solution. A binary-tree would lead to some redundancy because the nodes could be reached through different paths, as far as I understand. (2) I have my attempts not at hand but will add them as soon as I have access to my computer. (3) That's correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i now better understand what you want to enumerate so here is
another answer to your question for the alternative definition of
a “path”: a path can be described as a sequence of directions,
either down (0) or down right (1). That is trivially mapped
to an unsigned integer 0 ≤ `path` < 2<sup>`path-directions`</sup>
where each bit represents the successive directions. Each path is
conveniently represented by the pair (`path-directions`, `number`)
where `path-directions` is the number of directions, and `number`
encodes the successive directions in bits 0 through `path-directions`-1.

```
(defun gen-paths (path-directions)
  (loop for i below (expt 2 path-directions)
        collect i))
```

`(gen-paths 3)` => `(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)`

```
(defun path-to-directions (path-directions path)
  (loop for i downfrom (- path-directions 1) to 0
        collect (elt #(:down :down-right)
                     (ldb (byte 1 i) path))))
```

`(loop for path in (gen-paths 3) collect (path-to-directions 3 path))` =>

```
((:DOWN :DOWN :DOWN)             (:DOWN :DOWN :DOWN-RIGHT)
 (:DOWN :DOWN-RIGHT :DOWN)       (:DOWN :DOWN-RIGHT :DOWN-RIGHT)
 (:DOWN-RIGHT :DOWN :DOWN)       (:DOWN-RIGHT :DOWN :DOWN-RIGHT)
 (:DOWN-RIGHT :DOWN-RIGHT :DOWN) (:DOWN-RIGHT :DOWN-RIGHT :DOWN-RIGHT))
```

Note that `path-directions` is one less than the size of the
triangle. When you represent the path as the list of nodes you
have an extra element, the starting node (0, 0).

```
(defun path-to-ref (path-directions path)
  "Map a path to the list of (I J) pairs as understood by `get-node`."
  (loop for i upto path-directions
        for j = 0 then (+ j (ldb (byte 1 (- path-directions i)) path))
        collect (list i j)))
```

```
(loop with path-directions = (- (length *test*) 1)
      for path in (gen-paths path-directions)
      collect (path-to-ref path-directions path))
```

=>

```
(((0 0) (1 0) (2 0) (3 0)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 0) (3 1))
 ((0 0) (1 0) (2 1) (3 1)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 1) (3 2))
 ((0 0) (1 1) (2 1) (3 1)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 1) (3 2))
 ((0 0) (1 1) (2 2) (3 2)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 2) (3 3)))
```

```
(defun get-path-nodes (path triangle)
  "Returns the values of the nodes along PATH in TRIANGLE"
  (loop with path-directions = (- (length triangle) 1)
        for (i j) in (path-to-ref path-directions path)
        collect (get-node i j triangle)))
```

You can then easily get the values:

```
(loop with path-directions = (- (length *test*) 1)
      for path in (gen-paths path-directions)
      collect (get-path-nodes path *test*))
```

=>

```
((3 7 2 8) (3 7 2 5) (3 7 4 5) (3 7 4 9)
 (3 4 4 5) (3 4 4 9) (3 4 6 9) (3 4 6 3))
```

or sum them

```
(loop with path-directions = (- (length *test*) 1)
      for path in (gen-paths path-directions)
      collect (loop for v in (get-path-nodes path *test*)
                    sum v))
```

=>

```
(20 17 19 23 16 20 22 16)
```

Comment: That's great! I spent more than two hours without being able to wrap my brain around this abstract. I have learnt a lot from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Lisp unsurprisingly has friendlier support for lists, so I went with:

```
 (defparameter *pyre*
  '((3)
    (7 4)
    (2 4 6)
    (8 5 9 3)))
```

My first stab just collects a tree and is repetitive but perhaps easier to follow:

```
 (defun summit (n levels)
   (destructuring-bind (this . more) levels
    (let ((me (nth n this)))
      (if more
          (list
           (list* me (summit n more))
           (list* me (summit (1+ n) more)))
        (list me)))))
```

Test by evaluating:

```
 (summit 0 *pyre*)
```

Now tighten it up and compute the sums:

```
(defun summit (n levels)
  (destructuring-bind (this . more) levels
    (let ((me (nth n this)))
      (if more
          (loop for fork below 2
                nconc (summit (+ n fork) more) into fork-sums
                finally (return (loop for fs in fork-sums
                                      collecting (+ me fs))))
        (list me)))))
```

If recomputing paths concerns you, we could have some fun and rplaca the cons at one level with the sum of the existing car and each value computed at the next level. Left as an exercise.

Addendum: OK, no need for `rplaca` to avoid repeated calculations, to my great disappointment (but the moral is that recursion makes explicit path management unnecessary by funneling data along the paths implicit in the data):

```
(defun summit-ex (levels)
  (destructuring-bind (level . lower-levels) levels
    (if lower-levels 
      (loop with next-result = (let ((nr (summit-ex lower-levels)))
                                 (print nr)
                                 nr)
          for pos upfrom 0
          for value in level
          for next-values = (loop for fork below 2
                                  append (nth (+ pos fork) next-result))
          collect (loop for next-value in next-values
                        collecting (+ value next-value)))
      (mapcar 'list level))))
```

The debug printing was left in place because I like how they make clear what is going on:

```
((8) (5) (9) (3)) 
((10 7) (9 13) (15 9)) 
((17 14 16 20) (13 17 19 13)) 
((20 17 19 23 16 20 22 16))
```

Meanwhile, yes, some languages are more vector-friendly, such as Clojure:

```
(def pyre [[3]
           [7 4]
           [2 4 6]
           [8 5 9 3]])

(defn summit-ex [[level & lower-levels]]
  (if lower-levels
    (let [next-result (summit-ex lower-levels)]
      (for [pos (range (count level))]
        (let [value (nth level pos)
              next-values (mapcat #(nth next-result (+ pos %))
                                  [0 1])]
          (map #(+ value %) next-values))))
    (map list level)))
```

Me, I prefer Lisp.

Comment: Great inspiration! I wanted to use something else than a list because I thought it would cause to much memory consumption etc. Maybe this was wrong in the first place because using modern hardware the extra amount of memory is just neglectable. and treating the data even as a tree leads to more understandable code in the end. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Common Lisp compilers generate pretty decent/optimized code, and do pretty well with lists of course, so I would wait until I saw a problem before optimizing. Mind you, if you are coming from many other languages I would imagine the vector/array to be the most familiar/comfortable data structure, so it is understandable for a noob to start there. Give lists a chance.

Comment: I definitely will :-)

Comment: Really impressive! Although, as a newbie I find if quite confusing how you interlace recursion and multiple loops. E.g. if I am only interested in the maximum sum I have to add a wrapper on top extracting the list and reducing it, which is quite simple.

Comment: Heh-heh, do what I did: break it down to a trivial case such as ((3)(7 4)). Then look at the end condition of recursion, when no more data is available. That would be processing (7 4). My experience let me see a few moves ahead and wrap each in a list, but it would be ok to return the values and discover later that a higher level will be expecting each fork to produce a list of values. I went thru quite a few iterations to come up with that, so don't feel bad. And I prolly should not have used loop since that is a powerful but unlispy DSL I scorned for years before seeing the light.

Comment: Instead of a wrapper on top, check out ```labels```. You can move the recursive beef into an internal labels function summit-beef and then: (loop for sum in (first (summit-beef input-levels)) maximizing sum).

Answer (score 0):

To generate the “paths”, that is the sequence of `(i j)`s you can do:

```
(defun gen-paths (depth)
  (if (plusp depth)
      (loop for p in (gen-paths (- depth 1))
            nconc (loop for j to depth
                        collect (append p (list (list depth j)))))
      '(((0 0)))))
```

For example `(gen-paths 3)` =>

```
(((0 0) (1 0) (2 0) (3 0)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 0) (3 1)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 0) (3 2)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 0) (3 3))
 ((0 0) (1 0) (2 1) (3 0)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 1) (3 1)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 1) (3 2)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 1) (3 3))
 ((0 0) (1 0) (2 2) (3 0)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 2) (3 1)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 2) (3 2)) ((0 0) (1 0) (2 2) (3 3))
 ((0 0) (1 1) (2 0) (3 0)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 0) (3 1)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 0) (3 2)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 0) (3 3))
 ((0 0) (1 1) (2 1) (3 0)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 1) (3 1)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 1) (3 2)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 1) (3 3))
 ((0 0) (1 1) (2 2) (3 0)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 2) (3 1)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 2) (3 2)) ((0 0) (1 1) (2 2) (3 3)))
```

You can then map `get-node` into this to transform these indexes into the corresponding values:

```
(loop for path in (gen-paths 3)
      collect (loop for (i j) in path
                    collect (get-node i j *test*)))
```

=>

```
((3 7 2 8) (3 7 2 5) (3 7 2 9) (3 7 2 3)
 (3 7 4 8) (3 7 4 5) (3 7 4 9) (3 7 4 3)
 (3 7 6 8) (3 7 6 5) (3 7 6 9) (3 7 6 3)
 (3 4 2 8) (3 4 2 5) (3 4 2 9) (3 4 2 3)
 (3 4 4 8) (3 4 4 5) (3 4 4 9) (3 4 4 3)
 (3 4 6 8) (3 4 6 5) (3 4 6 9) (3 4 6 3))
```

or sum the values of each “path”

```
(loop for path in (gen-paths 3)
      collect (loop for (i j) in path
                    summing (get-node i j *test*)))
```

=>

```
(20 17 21 15 22 19 23 17 24 21 25 19 17 14 18 12 19 16 20 14 21 18 22 16)
```

Comment: That looks very interesting! But your solution gives to many paths. I guess my question was not clear enough about this detail. In my data structure you can only go directly down or down and one step to the right. If I find the time I will see if I can add this detail myself.